# How do I make an edit to only one part of a formula and copy down a formula so that everything but that one part is not changed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy, vlookup, xlookup

I have a list of rows each containing a production line name ("COM" in this example) and an xlookup formula:

```
=(SUMIFS('Go Get'!$H:$H, 'Go Get'!$B:$B, "COM",'Go Get'!$C:$C, "Production", 'Go Get'!$I:$I, "December"))/1000.
```

So for example the next row would be for the next production line ("PICT"):

```
=(SUMIFS('Go Get'!$H:$H, 'Go Get'!$B:$B, "PICT",'Go Get'!$C:$C, "Production", 'Go Get'!$I:$I, "December"))/1000
```

My file has months laid out individually in their own column. I want to change the formula so that the next month is the only thing changing and everything else stays the same (ie. the name of the production line and "Production"). Example for the next month:

```
=(SUMIFS('Go Get'!$H:$H, 'Go Get'!$B:$B, "COM",'Go Get'!$C:$C, "Production", 'Go Get'!$I:$I, "January"))/1000.
```

I want to copy this formula into each of the month columns and then down into the rows below so that the production line name stays the same and only the month changes.

Pulling the formula pulls all the data into the rest of the cells including the production line name and "Production" type. I want those to stay the same and only pull the "Month" value of the formula.

Comment: Maybe instead of hardcoding a string in the formula, refer to a cell with the string in it?